# Archivo Css no esta siendo cargado en una pagina razor asp net core 3.1

Tags: c#, css, api, asp.net-core, razor

espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema:

Empecé mi proyecto como una api, por especificaciones necesito enviar un pdf, tuve que configurar rotativa y añadir la carpeta wwwroot:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           }

           app.UseHttpsRedirection();

           app.UseRouting();

           app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

           app.UseAuthentication();

           app.UseAuthorization();

           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           {
               endpoints.MapControllers();
               endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name:"default",
                   pattern: "{Controller=TestPdf}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           });

           RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath,"../Rotativa");
       }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vista Razor que al ejecutar mi api y dirigirme a la acción del controlador me devuelva la vista.

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>Pdf</title>
   <link href="~/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
   <h1> Testing the pdf send from the backend</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les dejo tambien mi archivo csproj, por si de algo se referencian:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\Accounting\MasterDetails\**" />
    <Content Remove="Controllers\Accounting\MasterDetails\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Controllers\Accounting\MasterDetails\**" />
    <None Remove="Controllers\Accounting\MasterDetails\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Rotativa\css\general.css" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Rotativa\css\general.css">
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Rotativa.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0-beta" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\Tables\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\TableView\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\js\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\lib\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="app.yaml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><UserProperties appsettings_1json__JsonSchema="" /></VisualStudio></ProjectExtensions>


</Project>
```

efectivamente todo corre bien, a excepción que el css no me carga a la pagina Razor, ya intente con referenciarlo con url.content, y demás, pero no se que pueda estar pasando, agradezco cualquier comentario que me puedan ofrecer.

Saludos.

Comment: en tu metodo configure  agrega que usaras elementos estaticos:    app.UseStaticFiles();    esta es la referencia https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: eso era, como estaba con la plantilla base de la API, faltaba configurar eso en la app, muchas gracias, ponlo como respuesta asi la marco como tal en esta pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es sencillo agrega app.UseStaticFiles(); en tu Configure
por lo que tu codigo en tu metodo resulta:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       }
       app.UseStaticFiles();

       app.UseHttpsRedirection();

       app.UseRouting();

       app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

       app.UseAuthentication();

       app.UseAuthorization();

       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
           endpoints.MapControllers();
           endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name:"default",
               pattern: "{Controller=TestPdf}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       });

       RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath,"../Rotativa");
   }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, son detalles que se le escapan a uno